# What's Ruby's equivalent of cached_property in python?

Tags: ruby, properties, attributes

Basically, I have a Ruby class which has a  property to make expensive HTTP calls to get some value, I need the value to be cached, so next time I access the property I don't have to call HTTP again.

http://pydanny.com/cached-property.html

https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Cached_Properties

Is there a Ruby version for this?

Comment: Do you need the exact equivalent of the cached property (i.e. deleting the attribute should reset it, etc) or you are looking just for a convenient way to cache it? In the former case, it can be coded and may be there is a gem for that already. In the latter case use the memoization pattern: http://www.justinweiss.com/blog/2014/07/28/4-simple-memoization-patterns-in-ruby-and-one-gem/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the instance of your class persists, you would simply need to memoize the result.

```rb
class Foo
  def http_response
    @_http_response ||= begin
      # your slow I/O bound code here
    end
  end
end
```

Unless the result of that block is falsy, it won't be executed again. There are several variations on this concept, for example:

```rb
class Foo
  def http_response(skip_cache = false)
    return @_http_response unless skip_cache || !@_http_response
    @_http_response = fetch_http_response
  end

  private
    def fetch_http_response
      # your slow I/O bound code here
    end
end
```